# Copying or Replicating Amazon RDS MYSQL weekly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

What is the best practice for keeping an Amazon RDS UAT database refreshed weekly from a Production version of that database?  We were thinking of mirroring the production RDS, but we don't want any changes in UAT to be reflected in Production.  So the thought of taking a weekly backup of production and restoring it to the UAT, but this is time consuming.  Can we apply a snapshot of Production onto UAT if UAT is initially a restore of some point in time from Production?

Answer (score 0):

RDS offers two mechanisms for database backup/recovery.  You can utilize the automated backups to allow point in time database recovery/creation.  Alternately you can utilize database snapshots to make manual or automated snapshots that you can use to create new RDS instances.

Here is some more information from the AWS RDS FAQ: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#23

Comment: I understand those features and we use them.  I am looking to know if there is a preferred method for taking the production database, copying the backup to a UAT database and then keeping the UAT refreshed weekly from prod.  Not sure if there is a way to keep the UAT as a slave mirror, but it wont be a mirror as soon as someone changes something in UAT.

Comment: @Nungster In the past, I have used a EC2 micro instance to do nothing other run cron scripts for such automation purposes.  You just need an instance with AWS command line tools installed on it (or AWS SDK for your language of choice if you don't want to use command line scripting).