# How can I create Mirror of amazon MySQL RDS instance and connect to it?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How can I create Mirror of amazon MySQL RDS instance and connect to this instance,

I read about that amazon has automatic backup for RDS instances and automatic restores it, they have automated backup and DB snapshot, so i guess it's possible to connect to the DB snapshot.

Well i simply want to connect to a mirror of my production RDS instance so i can run heavy queries without affect the production performance.

I wasn't able to find in amazon FAQ ([http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712432/copying-or-replicating-amazon-rds-mysql-weekly))

This question also didn't help me to understand if i can do it and how
[Copying or Replicating Amazon RDS MYSQL weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712432/copying-or-replicating-amazon-rds-mysql-weekly)

Also a good reference will be here : http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#23 but i couldn't get what should be done in order to connect to such instance.

is it possible? can you explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. View the database instances
2. Click on the specific instance you want to replicate
3. Click `instance actions` and select `create read replica`.

If you need to create a read replica automatically take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-CreateDBInstanceReadReplica.html. You can use the command line tools to create a script that will create an instance on demand.

For information on amazons read replica see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html.

Here is an extract:

> Updates made to the source DB instance are replicated to the read
>   replica. The read replica handles read-only traffic from your
>   application, which can reduce the load on your source DB instance.
>   Read replicas allow you to elastically scale out beyond the capacity
>   constraints of a single DB instance for read-heavy database workloads.

Comment: is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: It automatically updates from the master, and won't go anywhere. Do you need to create/delete the instance on demand I assume?

Comment: Thanks, are you saying it's always updates from the original? like almost real time?

Comment: Yes I put a quote in my answer.